# How do I include padding in highlited item in kendo.listview?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-listview

I have created a kendo.listview object, and used the padding property to control the space between the text and the border. When an item is selected, only the text is highlighted and I want the entire row (border to border) to be highlighted. Any suggestions?

I want the listview object to be able to handle various size items, so using the min-width property is not ideal. However I am not set on using padding, so if there is some other way of controlling the distance between the text and border I am willing to apply it.